# What's the best way to do looping animations?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ipad, animation

The key word is looping. I'm thinking I would have two functions for an animation, such as a pulse. Is this the best way to make it loop?

```
-(void)animationPart1 {

    //Do first half of animation here, pulse in, the animation is 0.3 seconds long
    [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:0.3 target:self selector:@selector(animationPart2) userInfo:nil repeats:NO];

}

-(void)animationPart2 {

    //Do second half of animation here, pulse out, the animation is 0.3 seconds long
    [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:0.3 target:self selector:@selector(animationPart1) userInfo:nil repeats:NO];

}
```

I'm new to animations, so thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you use that approach, I think your should set "repeats" to "YES" and then you don't have to create a recursive loop like that.

Aside from that, without knowing precisely what you are attempting to animate, I do think there are a number of ways to approach animation such as Core Animation's "CABasicAnimation" which has a number of different ways to animate various things (see examples):

http://www.cimgf.com/2009/10/20/marching-ants-with-core-animation/

If you are doing very heavy animation such as a game, then use Cocos2D, it rocks.